# Plot parametric solutions using Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, parametric-functions

I want to plot the parametric diagram of `{y[t],z[t]}`, in which I manipulate a parameter, ω, from $[1, 10 \pi]$. Here is what I have attempted, but I can't get a plot. I think there is something wrong with my `Manipulate` expression.

Can anyone give me some advice?

```
Remove["Global`*"]

dieff = {y''[t] == ω z'[t], 
z''[t] == -ω y'[t] + ω E1/B};

inicond = {y[0] == y'[0] == z[0] == z'[0] == 0};

eqnlist = Join[dieff, inicond];

soln = DSolve[eqnlist, {y[t], z[t]}, t][[1]];

E1 = B = 1;

Print["y[t] = ", y[t] /. soln]
Print["z[t] = ", z[t] /. soln]

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[ {y[t], z[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 2}], {ω, 0, 10 π}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I post for insights into $\omega$ bounds:

```
fun[w_] := {y[t], z[t]} /. 
  First@DSolve[{y''[t] == w z'[t], z''[t] == -w y'[t] + w , 
     y[0] == y'[0] == z[0] == z'[0] == 0}, {y[t], z[t]}, t]
Manipulate[
 Column[{ParametricPlot[Evaluate[fun[w] /. t -> u], {u, 0, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {y[t], z[t]}], 
   Plot[Evaluate[fun[w] /. t -> u], {u, 0, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
    PlotLegends -> TraditionalForm /@ {y[t], z[t]}]}], {{w, 0, 
   "\[Omega]"}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 ubpdqn, you make the neatest animated examples that always further illuminate the question at hand!

Comment: @rasher thank you for the kind words...just thought important to notice solution blows out as $\omega$ passes around $2\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `Manipulate` to

```
With[{f1 = y[t] /. soln, f2 = z[t] /. soln}, 
 Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{f1, f2}, {t, 0, 2}], {ω, 0.1, 10 π}]]
```

Note also change to omega lower bound - you had division by zero with current example.

Comment: It works! But I think yours is essentially the same as mine;yet, mine wouldn't work. I'm confused.

Comment: @Lawerance: There's several ways to accomplish same thing, but while yours may *look* the same basically, what happens within `Manipulate` causes different outcome. See the documentation re: `Manipulate`, and the hows/whys of evaluation using it. There's a good tutorial overview as part of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
 Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[soln[[All, 2]] /.ω -> s, {t, 0, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}], {s, $MachineEpsilon, 10 π}]
```